# Search a value in BD stored with &aacute; element

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in my database that is stored with accents this way -> `S&aacute;nchez` for Sánchez. When I search by surname from an input field, if I type 'Sánc' or 'Sánch' I get the user properly, but if I search 'Sanchez' I'm getting no result back.

My query is : `Select name,surname,age FROM users WHERE surname LIKE ?`  Where the char `?` is `%param%`, for example -> %Sanch%.

Is there any way to 'avoid' the `&aacute; &eacute; &Aacute...` in the search?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any 'nice' solution to this problem so I had to add a new column at the database called 'clear_search'. This column stores the data with no accent or special char, so when you search for CITROËN, José or España it just searchs for a matching in this column.

Eg;

CITROËN gets stored as CITROEN
José as Jose
España as Espana